# Connection to MQTT broker via React Native error: Bad User Name or Password

Tags: react-native, mqtt

I'm developing a mobile app in React Native, and I'm trying to communicate to an MQTT server to receive informations about the chargers that I have connected to the server.

The question is:

**I can connect successfully to the mosquito server and receive messages, but I can't connect to my server**, the error is the following: MQTT CONNACK: Bad Username or Password.

[image: Logs from the application]

I've already tried many approaches, and still nothing. And the user and the password are 100% correct.
Here is my creation of the client.

[image: MQTT.CreateCLient]

It may help, this is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "buffer": "^5.6.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.3.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "~0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.1",
    "react-native-paho-mqtt": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "sp-react-native-mqtt": "^0.4.25",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: In future please do not post images of text (logs/code), post the actual text and use the tools to format it. Images can be hard to read and impossible for screen readers.

Comment: What is "my server" and how is it different from "mosquitto server"?!?  Are you testing to two different MQTT brokers?  [Note: They are "brokers", not "servers" ;) ]   What does "my server" logfile show?  I don't think you are suppose to have the port in the URI...that is what the 'port:' option is for.

Comment: @JDAllen I'm working with an Mqtt server in a Rasperry Pi, and I have access to it via the IP address. I can make the connection via this uri in Android Studio and in MQTT BOX application, but I can't here.

Comment: So your Android App and your MQTT BOX app can both connect to your RPi MQTT Broker using the same username and password as your code above?  But this code does not connect?  Again, what does the error log on the RPI MQTT Broker show when your code tries to connect?